# Export reprojected texture

Tags: texturing, uv, export, image, uv-image-editor

I'm not entirely sure how to explain this so I hope this makes sense to someone.

Essentially, I have this illustration which I have projected from viewport onto a concertina-folded plane. The idea is that this will be printed and folded in such a way that from a certain perspective it'll be visible as normal, but when flattened out or viewed from the wrong angle it'll be intentionally distorted.

[image: Image of concertina mesh with projected texture viewed at the angle where the image has no distortion]

[image: Image of mesh from another angle showing intended distortion]

Currently the only method I can think to export the distorted texture from Blender would be to manually unfold the mesh into a flat plane and do an orthographic render of that. Is there any other method that may be more simple?

[image: Image of manually unfolded mesh]

Is there any way to export a texture which warps to a uniform rectangular UV where all the edges are parallel, which could then be printed onto the physical concertina, perhaps?
I suppose I'm asking if it's possible to perform the opposite of how UVs are meant to be used, warping the image to fit a UV, instead of warping a UV to fit an image. The image below shows the current UV map with the zig-zag shape, can Blender somehow bake the texture to this UV map and then warp the texture with the UV, allowing me to straighten out the UV and therefore distort the texture?

[image: Image showing view-projected UV map]

Also, I'm wondering if there is any way to make the projection more accurate, at the moment it seems to still have some degree of distortion as opposed to looking exactly like the original texture once projected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*"UV project modifier"*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) to do that:

[image]

The principle: the modifier will take the *object* (often camera) as point of view to determinate UV map projection.